How to mask a numpy array base on coordinates
I have a 3D FITS data cube
the data is in [v,y,x] format, which indicates the velocity, y pixel and x pixel axis
the x,y pixels are parallel to GALACTIC longitude l and latitude b, like this:

and I want to cut this blue pentagon area in the middle:
229deg < l < 234deg 4deg < b < 14deg delta > -13deg
while delta is the declination in the equatorial coordinate system
so I need to transfer the condition delta > -13deg into galactic coordinate system
in fact, the right ascention line of delta = 13deg in galactic coordinate system is not a straight line
I don't know how to mask the array by coordinates
you can test on these FITS files:
https://cdsarc.cds.unistra.fr/ftp/J/A+A/594/A116/CUBES/GAL/CAR/

OK now I have an idea: I can make a 2D array with all pixel_to_world coordinates in (RA, DEC), and I can make a mask on that array, then I use the mask on the original data cube.

I can make a 2D array with all pixel_to_world coordinates in (RA, DEC), and I can make a mask on that array, then I use the mask on the original data cube.
y_height = data[0].shape[0]
x_width = data[0].shape[1]

x_indices, y_indices = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_width), np.arange(y_height))

# Convert pixel indices to world coordinates
world_coords = wcsc.pixel_to_world(x_indices, y_indices)

# Extract the DEC values and store them in the coord_array
coord_array_dec = world_coords.icrs.dec.value
coord_array_l = world_coords.galactic.l.value
coord_array_b = world_coords.galactic.b.value

import numpy.ma as ma

mask_dec = ma.masked_greater(coord_array_dec, -13).mask
mask_l1 = ma.masked_greater(coord_array_l, 229).mask
mask_l2 = ma.masked_less(coord_array_l, 234).mask
mask_b1 = ma.masked_greater(coord_array_b, 4).mask
mask_b2 = ma.masked_less(coord_array_b, 14).mask
mask = mask_dec * mask_l1 * mask_l2 * mask_b1 * mask_b2

masked_data = data * mask[np.newaxis, :, :]


